# I delete old messages from Apache Kafka but it's folder size is so high

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka messages are deleted with the retention settings and the data of the last 1 week is kept.  But the size of the directory where the kafka data is stored is 200gb. My last week's data is not 200gb. Old data not deleted? If it is not deleted, how can I access that data? I tried settings like --from-beginning, --offset "earliest" but I couldn't pull the data.

I ran this command :

`kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --deep-iteration --print-data-log --files /var/lib/kafka/data/xray.xray -0/00000000000001151540.log`And this timestamp returned : `1641543351488` .It is correspond to 7 jan

Comment: I ran this command :`kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --deep-iteration --print-data-log --files /var/lib/kafka/data/cars-0/00000000000001151540.log`   And this timestamp returned : 1641543351488 .It is correspond to 7 jan

Comment: Also show [offset shell](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-tools-GetOffsetShell.html) with the `-2` time option to get the earliest offsets that consumers can read

Comment: Ok I tried this : `kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092  --topic xray.xray  --time -2`  . I got these results :                           
xray.xray:0:176507580
xray.xray:1:162160260
xray.xray:2:118162415   Are these results normal?  .

Comment: Umm, well, that's a different topic than `cars`, which you showed before, so I'm not sure how that helps. But you tell us. The offsets there should match the lower bounds of the filenames in the the Kafka log segments

Comment: I edited as xray.xray. I spelled it wrong here . All results for xray.xray topic

Comment: `1151540` is definitely lower than `xray.xray:0:176507580`. I'm not really sure where else to check. Do you have unclean leader election disabled on the brokers? Have you recently restarted any brokers or performed any upgrades?

Comment: Actually, what I want to ask is that the data in kafka is being deleted, but why is the size of the kafka folder large? Or is it still not deleted? It's better for me if it's not deleted. I want to access old data as well, how do I do that?

Comment: And my point is that it seems Kafka broker protocol (OffsetShell) is returning higher offsets than are actually stored on disk (the filenames), meaning it's not deleting them appropriately (at least for the one replica you checked). If you actually want the data, and restarting the cluster doesn't fix it, I'm not really sure what else to check